# SQLite csv import issue value inf.0

Tags: string, sqlite, csv

I'm getting a strange issue importing a csv into Sqlite.

When I import the csv into the database, many of the values show up as "inf.0" as the value for one of the columns.
I have an `ItemID" column("STRING (16)")` with values that I want stored in my database with ID's like:

```
6E2500G0C0
6E26000003 
6E26000005
6E26F0T003
```

When imported they end up like:

```
6E2500G0C0
inf.0 
inf.0
6E26F0T003
```

I've also tried changing them by hand, but when I commit the change, they also change to the value "inf.0".

Can't seem to figure out what is causing these to show up this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table where you import the csv file already exists and you have defined the column's data type as `STRING` then according to [3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity) the column's affinity is actually `NUMERIC`.

So when you import the column values any value that could be interpreted as a number is implicitly converted to a number.
A value like `6E26000003` is interpreted like a number because it is considered to be a number in scientific notation:

```
6 * 10^26000003
```

which exceeds the limit of any numeric representation for SQLite and you get as result `inf.0` meaning infinite.

Change the column's data type to `TEXT` and you will import the csv column values as they are.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I also forgot to set the mode to `.mode csv`.